serve application stuck on "Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)" post Angular 13 upgrade
After Upgrading the application from Angular 12 to 13, running the application is stuck on "Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)" and its not proceeding further.
Tried to update few of the packages but no luck. have anyone experienced this, or can give me advice on how to move forward.
